# rails-footnotes and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, footnotes

I'd like to show notes only if user is admin. The official generated initilizer has the following rows:

```
  # Whether or not to enable footnotes
  f.enabled = Rails.env.development?
  # You can also use a lambda / proc to conditionally toggle footnotes
  # Example :
  # f.enabled = -> { User.current.admin? }
  # Beware of thread-safety though, Footnotes.enabled is NOT thread safe
  # and should not be modified anywhere else.
```

but I couldn't do better than this:

```
f.enabled = true
f.before {|controller, filter| filter.notes = controller.current_user.try(:admin?) ? [:controller, :view, :layout, :partials, :stylesheets, :javascripts, :assigns, :session, :cookies, :params, :filters, :routes, :env, :queries, :log] : []  }
```

It works but is it correct/safe? What I actually want is to emulate rails-footnots enabling by emptying or not the notes list. How can I use the official lambda notation? `User.current.admin?` does not make sense to me because model should not have access to session

Answer (score 1):

rails-footnotes fixed/improved after opening [issue](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/issues/128#issuecomment-86625686). Now you can do this:

```
f.enabled = proc { |controller| controller.current_user.try(:admin?) }
```